# AWS Api Gateway maximum resource limit per api

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, aws-limits

What is the hard limit for the resources per REST api in Api Gateway? As per AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table, default quota is 300 per api which can be increased on request.
My use is I have multiple versions of the apis which I am trying to add in single REST api in Api Gateway. Is there a hard limit at AWS beyond which they won't increase?

Comment: As you've noted the service hard limit is not documented.  I read in a post that it's only 400, however, haven't validated the actual value.  You can just request the service limit increase and see how it goes, there's no cost.